# How to handle going from one app back to your reactnative app

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I have an app, which when a phone call or another intent opens up.

when browsing back to my reactnative app, it goes back to the first screen and not returning to the last screen it was on. also all data is reset.

Steps:

1. page through till you get to the mainscreen (all is good)
2. accept a phone call (can accept)
3. end phone call (can end)
4. go back to the app (restarts the app flow)

```js
export const AppStack = () => {
    useKeepAwake();
    useEffect(() => {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        () => {
          return true;
        },
      );
      return () => backHandler.remove();
    });
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name={"splash:}
          component={SplashScreen}
          options={{detachPreviousScreen: true, gestureEnabled: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name={"login"}
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{detachPreviousScreen: true, gestureEnabled: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name={"main"}
          component={MainScreen}
          options={{detachPreviousScreen: true, gestureEnabled: false}}
        />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };
```